# I Cant delete constraints of table so i can drop it. ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to delete foreign key constraints in sqldeveloper so i can drop all tables, but it shows me the error in title when i try to do it. someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The table is currently being used; someone (maybe even you, in another session) performed DML on it and didn't commit (nor rollback) so the table is "busy". Once that transaction is done (by either committing or rolling back), you'll be able to drop that foreign key constraint.

Here's an example that shows two sessions that run in parallel; follow the numbers:

[image]

1. user A created the table that has a foreign key constraint to the DEPT table
2. user B - in another session, obviously - inserted a row into that table
3. user A tried to drop the constraint but was unable to because the table is still "busy"
4. user B commits
5. user A is now able to drop the constraint

Comment: so how do i commit/rollback in locked seesion?

Comment: You can't. User who is doing *something* with the table has to do it, which means that you'll have to find who that is. Maybe it was your session which terminated in unexpected way; Oracle will release locks automatically after some time. Or, talk to your DBA and ask them to *kill* the session that's holding the table - if they think that it is safe to be done.

Comment: do you know after how much time aprox will it release lock?

Comment: I wouldn't know.

Comment: stop the server, but ou culd loose some data

Comment: its college's server idk if i can stop it...